# Using splice on dynamic array in Angular repeater

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an issue when trying to delete an object from an array using splice. I have an array that is dynamically created through a UI and stored in a scope variable called $scope.productAttributes.Products. This is an example of what it looks like...

```
[
{
    "ProductLabel":"Net",
    "Code":"ela",
    "Site":"SITE1"
},
{
    "ProductLabel":"Link",
    "Code":"eli",
    "Site":"SITE1"
},
{
    "ProductLabel":"24-port managed PoE switch",
    "Code":"24p",
    "Site":"SITE2"
},
{
    "ProductLabel":"Dedicated Firewall",
    "Code":"ded",
    "Site":"SITE2"
},
{
    "ProductLabel":"Link",
    "Code":"eli",
    "Site":"SITE3"
},
{
    "ProductLabel":"IPv4 Addresses",
    "Code":"ip4",
    "Site":"SITE3"
}
]
```

I then display that array in an angular repeater and group it by 'site' (which might be part of the problem)...

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in productAttributes.Products | groupBy: 'Site'">
    <strong>{{key}}</strong>
    <div ng-repeat="site in value">
        <h4>{{site.ProductLabel}}</h4>
        <sapn href="" ng-click="deleteItem($index)" class="text-danger">Remove {{site.ProductLabel}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

On the delete button I pass in the index of the object and use the splice function...

```
 $scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
        $scope.productAttributes.Products.splice(index, 1);
};
```

So the issue is that the $index is always zero (I noticed this from a console.log) as I mentioned that I think it might be down to the groupBy but I am not sure. anyone know whats going wrong? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

It would seem the problem is with the $index in the nested repeater. So if the json above the structure would be...

SITE1:

Product: Net - $index: 0

Product: Link - $index: 1

SITE2:

Product: 24-port - $index: 0

Product: Dedicated - $index: 1

SITE3:

Product: Link - $index: 0

Product: IPV4 - $index: 1

So if I try to delete the IPV4 product in SITE3, it removes the LINK product in Site1 as it has the same $index. any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: what about `track by $index` ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Hey - thanks for your answer. I tried to that but it didnt work. when I added ng-repeat="site in value track by $index" it deletes the last object in the array

Comment: I've read at bit more on Track by and it seems it could be a fix. But I would need a unique identifier for each object in the array in order for it to work - right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can not rely on $index as it does not contain the updated value after you remove an item from array.

Pass the object dynamically from UI and delete it from model using below code:

**In Html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in productAttributes.Products | groupBy: 'Site'">
    <strong>{{key}}</strong>
    <div ng-repeat="site in value">
        <h4>{{site.ProductLabel}}</h4>
        <sapn href="" ng-click="deleteItem(site)" class="text-danger">Remove {{site.ProductLabel}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**In JavaScript:**

```
$scope.productAttributes.Products.splice
    ($scope.productAttributes.Products.indexOf(site), 1);
```

This causes model to update with updates values in repeater and re-renders it on UI.

Answer (score 2):

OK - I ended up doing it this way and it seems to work

```
$scope.deleteItem = function (item) {
        var index = $scope.productAttributes.Products.indexOf(item);
        $scope.productAttributes.Products.splice(index, 1);
    };
```

So passing in the whole object seems to have worked. I'm not sure why.

Comment: We both wrote the same at same time I guess. -- +1.:)